# How do you factor out common "before(:each)" calls in RSpec so that multiple specs can use them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, refactoring, rspec

I'd like to factor this bunch of code so that all of my controller tests (well, almost all of them) use this `before(:each)` block:

```
before(:each) do
  @user = User.new
  controller.stub(:authenticate_user!)
  controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(@user)
  controller.stub(:add_secure_model_data)
end
```

Is there any way to do that? I don't want to include it in all controllers... because there are a few that don't need this. By basically, every controller that extends from `SecureController` will need this `before(:each)` block.

Is there any nice way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/dir/example-groups/shared-context

```
shared_context "controller stuff" do
  before(:each) { ... }
end

describe SomeController do
  include_context "controller stuff"
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

So put the block into `SecureController.`

If there are specific children of `SecureController` that don't want this functionality, you could make another intermediate superclass, or wrap the method call with a conditional you control.